# Ruby on Rails- json url helper

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

My code is this:

```
$.getJSON("/somefolder/somefile.json?"+urlParams, function(json) {
    //populate combo here
});
```

I'm working on Rails, using sass and the file I have this code in is originally a file.js although to work with pipeline assets I already changed it to file.js.erb

In Dev I'm working in `http://localhost:XXXX` so results are OK.
In Prod I'm using a folder `http://domain.com:XXXX/app` so the results goes badways.

Coding like `<%=image_tag("loading.gif", :class => "loading")%>` works perfectly in this file but `$.getJSON("<%= controller_method_path %>.json?"+urlParams` does not

Any suggestion?

Comment: How is this not clear? `<%=image_tag("loading.gif", :class => "loading")%>` works and `<%= controller_method_path %>` doesn't in a *.js.erb file...anyways found the solution, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your routes are setup to use a prefix in production, you should be using the actual routing methods for the full path.

```
$.getJSON("<%= thingies_url(@thingy, :json) %>?"+urlParams, ...
```

Now the entire path should be generated properly in all cases.

---

But craziness like this is why it's usually not recommend to run rails apps in a subdirectory of a domain. It makes routing and relative links to other pages and assets much more of a headache.

If you can host the rails app on a subdomain instead.

```
# not awesome :(
http://mydomain.com/myapp

# totally awesome! :D
http://myapp.mydomain.com/
```

Comment: A colleague of mine found the answer, in Config>initializers I added a cusomization file so that helpers are added to all files I post here: `Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval do
  include ActionView::Helpers
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end`